# Long-formatting multiple wide-format data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Following up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74882312/16762740), I was wondering if there is a way to turn my wide-format data.frames (`time1`,`time2`,`time1and2`) into a single long-format data.frame to achieve my `Desired_output` below?

```r
time1 = read.table(text = "
class id   order ac bc
1     1    s-c   1  2
", header = TRUE)

time2 =read.table(text = "
class id   order ac bc
1     1    s-c   3  4
", header = TRUE)

time1and2 = read.table(text = "
class id   order ex1S ex2S ex1C ex2C  k1   k2   t1  t2
1     1    s-c   8    5    6     1    400  600  30  50
", header = TRUE)
```

```r
Desired_output = read.table(text = "
class id   order time DV score   k   t  ave_ex
1     1    s-c   1    ac 1      400  30 (8+5)/2 =6.5
1     1    s-c   1    bc 2      400  30 (8+5)/2 =6.5
1     1    s-c   2    ac 3      600  50 (6+1)/2 =3.5
1     1    s-c   2    bc 4      600  50 (6+1)/2 =3.5 
", header = TRUE)
```

where `ave_ex` = average of `ex`.

Comment: Why are ex1S and ex2S associated with time 1 in your output, rather than ex1S and ex1C? As given, there is no obvious way to associate those columns with the rows in your intended output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make them long format:

```
time1 <- pivot_longer(time1, c(ac, bc), names_to = "DV", values_to = "score") %>% mutate(time = 1) 
time2 <- pivot_longer(time2, c(ac, bc), names_to = "DV", values_to = "score") %>% mutate(time = 2) 
time1and2 <- pivot_longer(time1and2, c(k1:t2), names_to = c(".value", "time"), names_sep = "(\\d)") %>% 
  mutate(time = 1:2)
```

Then, unite:

```
bind_rows(time1, time2) %>% left_join(time1and2) %>% 
  mutate(ave = case_when(
    time == 1 ~ mean(c(ex1S, ex2S)),
    time == 2 ~ mean(c(ex1C, ex2C))
  )) %>%
  select(-c(ex1S:ex2C))

#Joining, by = c("class", "id", "order", "time")
## A tibble: 4 × 9
#  class    id order DV    score  time     k     t   ave
#  <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     1     1 s-c   ac        1     1   400    30   6.5
#2     1     1 s-c   bc        2     1   400    30   6.5
#3     1     1 s-c   ac        3     2   600    50   3.5
#4     1     1 s-c   bc        4     2   600    50   3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Stack `ac` and `bc` columns in `time1` and `time2` and bind them by row.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- list(time1, time2) %>%
  map_dfr(~ pivot_longer(.x, ac:bc, names_to = "DV", values_to = "score"), .id = "time")

#   time  class    id order DV    score
#   <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 1         1     1 s-c   ac        1
# 2 1         1     1 s-c   bc        2
# 3 2         1     1 s-c   ac        3
# 4 2         1     1 s-c   bc        4
```

**Step 2:** In `time1and2`, you need to rename `ex1S, ex2S, ex1C, ex2C` to `ex11, ex21, ex12, ex22` at first (here I use `chartr()` to achieve it), so that you can stack the pairs of columns

- `(ex11, ex12)` to `ex1`
- `(ex21, ex22)` to `ex2`
- `(k1, k2)` to `k`
- `(t1, t2)` to `t`

at the same time.

```r
df2 <- time1and2 %>%
  rename_with(~ chartr("SC", "12", .x), starts_with("ex")) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    ex11:t2,
    names_to = c(".value", "time"),
    names_pattern = "(.+)(.)"
  )

# time1and2 (Before)
#   class id order ex1S ex2S ex1C ex2C  k1  k2 t1 t2
# 1     1  1   s-c    8    5    6    1 400 600 30 50
#
# df2 (After)
#   class    id order time    ex1   ex2     k     t
# 1     1     1 s-c   1         8     5   400    30
# 2     1     1 s-c   2         6     1   600    50
```

**Step 3:** Merge them by `time`, `class`, `id`, and `order` and calculate the averages of `ex1` and `ex2`.

```r
left_join(df1, df2) %>%
  mutate(ave_ex = (ex1 + ex2) / 2)

# # A tibble: 4 × 11
#   time  class    id order DV    score   ex1   ex2     k     t ave_ex
#   <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 1         1     1 s-c   ac        1     8     5   400    30    6.5
# 2 1         1     1 s-c   bc        2     8     5   400    30    6.5
# 3 2         1     1 s-c   ac        3     6     1   600    50    3.5
# 4 2         1     1 s-c   bc        4     6     1   600    50    3.5
```